# Understanding a makefile script for Linux

Tags: linux, makefile

I am using fpgalink fx2 to build  on a Windows machine. Here is makefile what is meaning of following script :

```
BRANCH := $(shell TRY=$(CURDIR)
BRANCH=dev
while [ "$${TRY}" != "$(ROOT)" -a "$${TRY}" != "/" ]; do
    if [ -e "$${TRY}/.branch" ]; then
        BRANCH=$$(cat "$${TRY}/.branch") 
        break
    fi
    TRY=$$(dirname $${TRY})
done
echo $${BRANCH})
```

Comment: Why the downvote??? I redressed it.

Answer (score 1):

This GNU Makefile fragment is setting the value of the `BRANCH` Makefile variable.

It does this by invoking a short shell script, coded inline in the Makefile.

The shell script tries to find a file called `.branch` in the current directory.  If that file is not found, it tries to find it in the directory above, and so on until it either hits the root directory (`/`) or it hits the directory given by the value of the Makefile variable `ROOT`.

In case it finds the file, the contents of the file will be used to set the value of `BRANCH` (and the loop terminates).  If it doesn't find a `.branch` file anywhere, the `BRANCH` variable will be set to the value `dev`.